# Как заполнить множество textbox циклом в C# ?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Есть массив чисел mass. Надо загнать его в компоненты textbox через цикл, дабы уменьшить размер кода. Делаю примерно так

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
      {
           this.Controls["textbox" + i.ToString()].Text = mass[i-1];
      }
```

Вылетает с ошибкой "В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект."
В чём проблема? 
Пробовал внутри цикла писать вот так:

```
cls.frm1.Controls["textbox" + Convert.ToString(i)].Text = mass[i-1];
```

(тут cls - класс, а frm1 - форма), но всё без толку. Та же ошибка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cls.frm1.Controls["textbox" + Convert.ToString(i)]` у Вас явно возвращает null.

У Вас `TextBox` точно лежит непосредственно на форме? Свойство `Controls` содержит только те контролы, которые непосредственно лежат на форме.

Comment: Аа, точно. TextBox лежит внутри GroupBox'а. В таком случае, как тут указать ?
UPD:
Нет, дело не в GroupBox. После перемещения компонентов на голую форму, ничего не изменилось. Та же ерунда.

Comment: возможно дело в регистре? обычно дефолтные названия выглядят так: ``textBox1``

Comment: Нет, регистр не причём. После нескольких опытов установил, что работает код, только если использовать this и при этом textbox'ы находятся на голой форме (не в GroupBox'ах) + они обязательно должны быть не пустыми. Может быть знаете, как указать путь к ним внутри группировщика?

Comment: у групбоксов тоже есть свойство ``Controls``, пройтись по ним, или же через ``ControlCollection`` получить все групбоксы и по ним уже пройтись по всем контролам внутри них

Comment: Спасибо, так всё работает!