# Набор текстовых полей (TextBox) и цикл

Tags: c#, циклы

Есть такой вопрос. Имеется множество текстбоксов. Нужно все их перебрать в цикле (для проверки на заполненность). Как это можно сделать? Как к textBox привязать хвостик в виде его порядкового номера? Замучился уже гуглить, может, знает кто?

Comment: какая технология? winforms, webforms, mvc ... ?

Comment: winform....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button

Comment: На самом деле, вы что-то делаете не так. Почему вы с одной стороны не _создаёте_ текстбоксы в цикле, а с другой стороны пытаетесь _прочитать_ их в цикле?

Я бы посоветовал создавать текстбоксы в цикле и запоминать в контейнере, тогда все проблемы отпадут.

Comment: согласен с VladD.
У Вас задачи нет конкретной, поэтому замучались. Опишите, что хотели сделать, что это за TextBoxes, зачем нужны и зачем перебирать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну, в общем и целом:

```
        foreach (var control in Controls)
        {
            var textBox = control as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
                {
                    textBox.Text += string.Format("[{0}]", textBox.TabIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    // не заполнен
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите схожие ответы:

[Как заполнить множество textbox циклом в C# ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72776/net-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-textbox-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-c)

[Как перебрать объекты textBox в цикле?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74110/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-textbox-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5)